# How do I include a custom framework (GitHub's Mantle) into my iOS 6 project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, github-mantle

I want to use Github's Mantle framework in my iOS application. I am using XCode 4.5 and iOS SDK 6. How do I go about doing so?

This is the framework: https://github.com/github/Mantle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using [CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods) to manage your projects' dependencies. It works just like Ruby gems, and you only have to do this:

#### Add a file named `Podfile`

```
platform :ios
'Mantle', '0.2'
```

#### Then install dependencies

```
$ gem install cocoapods
$ pod install
```

After this last command, don't use your `.xcodeproj` anymore. Use the `.xcworkspace`.

#### To look for other frameworks

```
$ pod search restkit // For instance
```

Comment: Also, thanks for the restkit example. Looks like an awesome framework I intend to use.

Comment: What do you mean? Git submodules?